# Implementing a parent children object in .Net, SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

I have developed a web application with a timesheet object. The object has as property a List. In SQL Server this is reflected in 2 tables, Timesheets and TimesheetEntries, with TimesheetEntries having a foreign key pointing to the PK (Id autonumber) of the Timesheets table.
Currently the timesheet object is displayed on a grid where the user makes inserts and amendments to the entries and finally saves it.

In saving the timesheet, I delete all timesheet entries and then re-create them. Of course this pushes the autonumber field of the TimesheetEntries up every time the user saves the timesheet.

Is this the best way to achieve this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your timesheet entries instead of delete and then re-create all of them. Using your primary key, it will be easy to know which ones need to be updated.

Also, you can automate a lot of this by using an [Object-relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) for instance.

Comment: thanks for this; the way i see it though is that I may have to insert new entries (which were not part of the timesheet, but which have been inserted), delete the ones which are no longer part of the timesheet and finally update the ones that have changed...is that too much work for the Data Access Layer?

Comment: IMHO, such operations should sit in your Business Layer rather that the DA Layer...

Comment: What you suggest is really interesting...I was under the impression that the BLL should only worry about Timesheet.Save() type of operations. It would then call methods in lower layers (such as Service Layer or Data Access Layer) to co-ordinate these DB operations....

Answer (score 0):

The value of an auto incrementing identity column has no relevance within your business domain.  It is purely used as for uniqueness and in logical relationships within your data structure.  So, yes, it is fine that this field is incrementing.  Anyway, your relationship occurs between the TimeSheetEntry's FK and the TimeSheet PK.

Instead of deleting and reinserting these records, it may be better to update them.  I'm unsure of your requirements/business problem here so cannot comment further.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a little additional work, there's not much of a problem with the way that you're doing things.  Deletion and re-creation of child objects is a common approach.

Have to say though, it shouldn't actually matter that the auto-incrementing number is pushed up.  All of your timesheet entries should be retrievable through the corresponding timesheet foreign key.

You should not have rely on an auto-generated numbers.  It shouldn't matter that the ID field is going up.  Your real solution is to find a consistent way to retrieve them correctly, irrespective of what the surrogate keys might be.

**EDIT**

In response to user's comment.

You'll still use auto-numbers for PKs and FKs, but you should combine that with a means of uniquely identifying the big stuff, which is normally the stuff at the top of your object graph.

I implement this by including an Alias column in my database.

This is a unique varchar constraint which lives on anything that I might want to explicitly look up.

Consider the following example.

```
CREATE TABLE OrderTypes
(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(100),
  Alias varchar(30),
  Active bit,
  ...
)
```

Now I don't want to look up an `OrderType` by Id, because that could change if I ever have to rebuild the DB from scratch.

I don't want to look up an `OrderType` by name either.  What if someone changes the order type through a CMS function?

The Alias concept allows me to give each order type a short name that is **uneditable from any of the admin screens**.

Continuing the `OrderType` example, I might give Purchase Orders an alias of "`purchaseorder`" and Sales Orders and alias of "`salesorder`".

When I want to get the OrderType row that relates to sales orders, I can then use:-

```
SELECT * FROM OrderTypes WHERE Alias = 'salesorder'
```

At this point, your query has the auto-generated ID, so you can make further queries based on that value.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderTypeId = <that value I just safely derived>
```

This is a much better approach than hard-coding for auto-generated IDs.

Comment: so what you suggest is to not use the auto numbers as FK and PK?